# ¿Como listar un JSON usando BUTTON?

Tags: java, mysql, jquery, json, struts

> Tengo un problema con mi código. Quiero listar mi entidad "Persona" pero dependiendo de mi entidad "Distrito". Al escoger un distrito "x" y presionar click en el Boton "Consultar" me liste solo las personas de ese distrito. Me lista las personas de ese distrito cuando selecciono en el combobox pero no me lista cuando le doy click en el BOTON, no se que me falta, aun soy nuevo programando.
>
> este es mi JSP, y en el boton le pase la funcion "listarPersona()" pero no me lista.
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>       <h3 align="center">Lista Empleados</h3>
>           <label class="col-lg-1 control-label" for="id_reg_nombre">Distrito</label>
>                                               <div class="col-lg-5">
>                                                   <select id="idDistrito" name="persona.codigoDistrito" class='form-control'>
>                                                            <option value="-1" >[SELECCIONE]</option>
>                                                    </select>
>                                               </div>
>
>                   <button type="button" onclick="listarPersona()"
>                   class='btn btn-primary' >Consultar</button><br>&nbsp;<br>
>
>
>           <div id="divEmpleado">
>                                       <table id="id_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
>                                               <thead>
>                                                       <tr>
>                                                           <th>Codigo</th>
>                                                           <th>Nombre</th>
>                                                           <th>Apellido</th>
>                                                           <th>Nombre Distrito</th>
>                                                       </tr>
>                                               </thead>
>                                               <tbody id=tabla>
>
>                                               </tbody>
>                                           </table>    
>           </div>  
>   </div>
> ```
>
> este es mi codigo JQUERY cree mi funcion "listarPersona" pero no me funciona el boton pero el codigo que esta dentro de la funcion "listarPersona" lo pongo en el ".ready" me funciona pero con el combobox y no con el boton.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var codigoDistrito=0;
>
>   $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
>       $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
>   });
>
>
>   function cargarTipo(){
>       //leer json
>       $.getJSON("listarDistritos",{},
>               function(data){
>               $.each(data.listaDistritos,function(index,item){
>                   $("#idDistrito").append("<option value='"+item.codigo+"'>"+
>                           item.nombre+"</option>");                   
>               })  
>       })
>   }
>
>   function listarPersona(){
>       $("#idDistrito").change(function(e){
>           //obtener el codigo del tipo seleccionado
>           var cod;
>           cod=$(this).val();
>           //limpiar select "nivel""
>           $("#tabla").empty();
>           $.getJSON("listarPersonaXDistrito",{codigoDistrito:cod},
>                   function(data){
>                       $.each(data.listaPersonas,function(index,item){
>                           if(codigoDistrito==item.codigoDistrito)
>                           $("#id_table").append("<tr><td>"+item.codigo+"</td>"+
>                                     "<td>"+item.nombre+"</td>"+
>                                     "<td>"+item.apellido+"</td>"+
>                                     "<td>"+item.codigoDistrito+"</td><tr>");
>                       else
>                           $("#id_table").append("<tr><td>"+item.codigo+"</td>"+
>                                     "<td>"+item.nombre+"</td>"+
>                                     "<td>"+item.apellido+"</td>"+
>                                     "<td>"+item.codigoDistrito+"</td><tr>");
>
>
>                   })
>           })
>       })
>   }
>
>   $(document).ready(function() {
>       cargarTipo();
>       $('#id_table').DataTable();
>   });
> </script>
> ```